# chrome in headless mode not able to connect via webrtc

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webrtc, stun

When trying to automate one of the webrtc use case via selenium in **chrome-headless** mode,

I configured following options:

```
caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "chrome"}
chromePrefs := make(map[string]interface{})
chromePrefs["profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic"] = 1
chromePrefs["profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera"] = 1
chromeCaps := chrome.Capabilities{
    Path: "",
    Args: []string{
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream",
        "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
        "--headless",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
    },
    Prefs: chromePrefs,
}
caps.AddChrome(chromeCaps)
```

Here I am just using golang selenium wrapper from https://github.com/tebeka/selenium which is over original java driver

So the observation is

1. in GUI mode(without headless) chrome is generating ice candidate for all the interfaces in my PC and
   it connects well with remote peer
2. In Headless mode, it generates only 1 ICE candidate with type host with mdns example:3`92f939d-6507-45e1-87da-19b63fb76a9e.local` and not anymore and ice connection is failing as remote peer I am using is in not compatible to parse mdns

To overcome I added a STUN server support with peerconnection configured to use example

```
var peerConnectionConfig = { 'iceServers': [{ 'url': 'stun:192.189.67.565:3478' }], 'bundlePolicy': 'max-bundle'};
```

And I can clearly see via wireshark, *STUN Binding Request* is sent and successful mapped *Binding Success Response* address(192.185.46.57) is sent in return, but its not used by chrome to generate additional ice candidates in this **headless** mode

I would like to know is there any additional/different configuration essential for chrome-webrtc-ice connections to work when using in headless mode?

Thanks

Comment: headless doesn't support preference

Answer (score 0):

preference is not supported for headless browser

As of Feb , 2021

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

Headless chrome doesn't support preferrences setting . You can use command line arguments only.

the full list of supported arguments are :

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Here you can see --blink-settings so ,

try

```
chrome_options.add_arguments('--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=random_audio.wav')
chrome_options.add_arguments('--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=random_audio.y4m')
```

Comment: Setting media(Audio and Video) is not my actual concern, I am able to set it. But ICE candidates triggered are different when compared in headless vs GUI scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it works, I have tried it for myself. I believe it is this issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=776649

The application I am testing confirms my suspicion in the logs:

```
2021-02-31 17:27:19.240 Available media devices: 
2021-02-31 17:27:19.241 :  audioinput
2021-02-31 17:27:19.241 :  videoinput
2021-02-31 17:27:19.241 :  audiooutput
2021-02-31 17:27:19.256 Local media is not present NotSupportedError: Not supported
2021-02-31 17:27:19.256 No local media configured
```